# deleting a file after uploading to s3 in python

Tags: python, amazon-s3

```
def upload(s):
     conn=tinys3.Connection("AKIAJPOZEBO47FJYS3OA","04IZL8X9wlzBB5LkLlZD5GI/",tls=True)
     f = open(s,'rb')
     z=str(datetime.datetime.now().date())
     x=z+'/'+s
     conn.upload(x,f,'crawling1')
     os.remove(s)
```

The file is not deleting after i upload to `s3` it is not deleting in the local directory any alternate solutions?

Answer (score 0):

You have to close the file before you can delete it:

```
import os

a = open('a')
os.remove('a')
>> Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "main.py", line 35, in <module>
      os.remove('a')
   PermissionError: [WinError 32] The process cannot access the file because 
   it is being used by another process: 'a'
```

You should add `f.close()` before the call to `os.remove`, or simply use `with`:

```
with open(s,'rb') as f:
    conn = tinys3.Connection("AKIAJPOZEBO47FJYS3OA","04IZL8X9wlzBB5LkLlZD5GI/",tls=True)
    z = str(datetime.datetime.now().date())
    x = z + '/' + s
    conn.upload(x, f, 'crawling1')
os.remove(s)
```